# Images and Buttons not filling grid cells WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, grid, stretch

So I have 2 similar problems with the below image. The image is of a UserControl that has been added to a viewbox inside another UserControl:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeIqw.png)

1. The button in the top-left does not fill the whole of the grid cell, but the image within it fills the whole button .I have been trying out different methods of binding button images. This is why this is not the same for the other buttons in the grid. However I can't see how they should differ
2. The black images on the centre top, left, right, and bottom buttons don't fill their buttons. However, when editing the code, the designer shows them filling those buttons. The code for these is identical to the ContentControl above, but has an image path linking to a completely black image instead.

Was wondering if these problems might be related or have a similar fix? I've tried using extra viewboxes and stretch to fill/ alignment parameters but they seem to make no difference.

EDIT:

Implementing Location.xaml in parent UserControl:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10 10 10 10">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentLocationViewModel}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locationViewModel:SmallRoomViewModel}">
                        <locationView:SmallRoomView/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locationViewModel:LargeRoomViewModel}">
                        <locationView:LargeRoomView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </Viewbox>
```

SmallRoomView.xaml (the UserControl in the image):

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Button x:Key="wallTile" x:Shared="false" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown" Style="{StaticResource appWallTile}"/>
            <Button x:Key="floorTile" x:Shared="false" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown" Style="{StaticResource appFloorTile}"/>
            <Button x:Key="doorTile" x:Shared="false"  PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown" Style="{StaticResource appDoorTile}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" PreviewMouseDown="OnMouseDown">
        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding tile0_0}"/>
    </Button>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{StaticResource doorTile}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="{StaticResource wallTile}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="appDoorTile" TargetType="Button" x:Shared="false">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="./AllResources/images/tiles/doorTile.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="appFloorTile" TargetType="Button" x:Shared="false">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="./AllResources/images/tiles/floors/floorTile.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="appWallTile" TargetType="Button" x:Shared="false">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="./AllResources/images/tiles/walls/wallTile.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: The problem is in some markup you've not shown us. Please change your post to include a minimal reproduction.  Simplify this down. Just use background on your button rather than any png for this.

Comment: Also. Don't put UI in resources in that way. You can template out UI fine but if you put a button in there then you can only use it in one place. Which means you're better just having the button wherever you want to use it than resources.

Comment: I believe that's the most of it. I've been using a black image rather than a black button background for simplicity as then every button image has its source bound to a file path in the ViewModel

Comment: If you want that viewbox is to fill a cell then why's it got a margin?

Comment: Why aren't you just putting a button in each cell rather than all that stuff with content control, viewbox etc.  You should start with simple first then iterate.Add or change a bit, see what happens. If it breaks you know whatever little bit you changed broke it.

Comment: I've been using the viewbox's capability to automatically resize its contents when the window size has changed. The content controls were originally used so they could all access a button resource (so I only needed to change the properties of the button in one place), however I moved to the approach used for the top-left button so that I could bind the image to it. I noticed that this suddenly made the buttons smaller so was wondering if there was an easy fix?

Comment: Did you remove the margin?

Comment: Yes, the margin was just used in the parent UserControl to add padding to the outside of the child UserControl so that it wasn't right up against the edge of the screen.